# R: speed up 'table()' operation for a data.table object

Tags: r, data.table

I want like convert a data.table object to the following condition by using `table` function. That means, `colb` as colnames, and `cola` as rownames, and then if the individual `col` include corresponding `row`, then put the entry as `1`, otherwise `0`. I do it like this:

```
dt <- data.table(cola = c(1, 1, 2, 3), colb = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
dt
table(dt)

> dt
   cola colb
1:    1   10
2:    1   20
3:    2   30
4:    3   40
> table(dt)
colb
cola 10 20 30 40
   1  1  1  0  0
   2  0  0  1  0
   3  0  0  0  1
```

But when the data set is big, for example 39-million rows by 2 columns in my case, the table operation cost ~80 seconds to finish.

I would like to know is there more efficient method to do the same thing as table function did?

In addition, `dcast.data.table(dt, cola ~ colb, fill = 0L)` do the same thing when I try it, but the resutls have a little different which should be futher deal with to get the same results as table function. The important thing is that `dcast.data.table` do not improve the speed when I try my data. So, I hope someone can help to work out more efficient method to do the same thing!

Thank you.

Comment: Surprising that `dcast()` and `table()` have the same performance.. Never heard that before. In any case, performance issues are hard to answer unless we've access to the data you're working on (or at the least simulated data). Also, please post your `sessionInfo()` output.

Comment: I was also surprised that `table` operations seemed to be slower in data.table with 7 million rows than they were in dataframes. I'm working with an older Mac SL -build but current version, and data.table 1.9.4. I was doing the table operation as a j-argument inside "[". I had other more complicated functions that I found difficult to port over to data.table and just went back to my old dataframe ways.

Comment: @BondedDust what kind of complicated functions? Maybe post a question and we will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Arun: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocInstaller_1.16.1 data.table_1.9.5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics, thanks. I've tested it with dummy data on your dimensions. `table()` seems quite efficient here (~50s on mine). The `CJ` step is killing us here (internal implementation also uses `CJ`). Good to know there are improvements possible. Will update when/if I find a way to improve this.

Comment: @Arun. thanks. Waiting for your improvement.

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics I'm curious - given how large and sparse the resulting wide table is - what exactly is the point of this operation?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The complications for me had to do with the fact that I was passing in column names as character values and then constructing multiple tables with `do.call` and `tapply` and "[" and then taking elementwise ratios of matrices. I did give thought to building a MRE and posting . Perhaps I will.

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics, improvements aside, I'm curious too. The wide data is too sparse (your original data is ~300Mb, and after casting it'd result in ~3Gb).

Comment: @Arun and eddi: Actually, what I want finally is the same: Intersect all possible combinations of list elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614391/intersect-all-possible-combinations-of-list-elements) and then use 'Ananda Mahto' method.

Comment: @eddi, the question I ask here is one of steps according to Ananda's method.

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics, I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27771045/559784) using Matrix package, which deals very efficiently with sparse matrices might be the way to go here.. But I'll add this to the list of possible places for enhancements.

Comment: For the future, explaining the actual task (briefly) would save everyone's time.

Comment: @Arun, thanks. I just use 'slam' Package to solve my problem. The question is how can I get such sparse matrix. That is the reason I ask here. I actually had solved my final question, but I just want to improve the speed.

Comment: Good to know. As for your Q, using the function `sparseMatrix()` as shown in the answer linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Thanks @Arun and all. Yes, `sparseMatrix` can solve my original qestions. Here I list the answer (according to [Arun's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759882/how-to-create-a-matrix-of-different-format-from-a-data-frame-in-r/27771045#27771045)) . Here is just an demo example [I originally hope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614391/intersect-all-possible-combinations-of-list-elements):

```
dt <- data.table(sid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2), 
                 aid = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300))
dt
library(Matrix)
sm <- sparseMatrix(dt[, sid], dt[, aid], x = TRUE)   
cp <- t(sm) %*% sm   
cp <- summary(cp)  
cp <- cp[cp$i < cp$j, ]     
as.data.frame(cp)
    i   j x
4 100 200 3
7 100 300 2
8 200 300 2
```

This method is more efficent than I used before (['Ananda Mahto' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614391/intersect-all-possible-combinations-of-list-elements)). The time comparison for my data set (39763098 rows and 2 columns): ~141 seconds VS ~40 seconds for my original method and Arun's method respectively. So Thanks, it is perfect.
Second, Hope that for my current post's question, data.table can give a improvement too. You will.